# Django: Filter queryset by property of Element

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models, Chat and DeletedChat. Now i want to get all chats of a `user`, removing those which `from_date`-fields, in `DeletedChat`, are bigger then the `last_updated` ones of the chat itself. How do i do that?

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class DeletedChat(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    from_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And in my `views.py` I tried:

```
chat_ids = request.user.deletedchat_set.exclude(from_date__lt='chat__last_updated').values_list('chat', flat=True)
```

which gives me the following error: `['“chat__message__set__last” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']`

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with an `F` object to refer to a field:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q

Chat.objects.filter(Q(deletedchat=None) | Q(deletedchat__form_date__lt=F('last_updated')))
```

This will return `Chat` objects for which there is *no* related `DeletedChat` object, or where the `DeletedChat` object has a `form_date` that is less than the `last_updated` field of the `Chat` object.

We can also make use of `.exclude()`:

```
from django.db.models import F

Chat.objects.exclude(deletedchat__form_date__gte=F('last_updated'))
```

The two are however not equivalent if there are *multiple* related `DeleteChat` objects. In that case the `.filter(..)` variant can still contain a `Chat` if there exists at least one related `DeleteChat` object for which the `from_date` is less than the `last_updated` field. For the `.exclude()`, it will exclude it from the moment one of the `from_date`s is greater than the `last_updated` field.

In case a `Chat` object has at most one `DeletedChat` object, you might want to conider a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) instead.

Comment: thanks. i think you have a typo in your second example, it should be `exclude` instead of `filter`, am i right? In case somebody else should need this answer.